# DBSCAN with ball_tree and metric haversine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have this code of class from a journal which uses euclidean metric :

```
    class ST_DBSCAN():
        """
        A class to perform the ST_DBSCAN clustering
        Parameters
        ----------
        eps1 : float, default=0.5
            The spatial density threshold (maximum spatial distance) between 
            two points to be considered related.
        eps2 : float, default=10
            The temporal threshold (maximum temporal distance) between two 
            points to be considered related.
        min_samples : int, default=5
            The number of samples required for a core point.
        metric : string default='euclidean'
            The used distance metric - more options are
            ‘braycurtis’, ‘canberra’, ‘chebyshev’, ‘cityblock’, ‘correlation’,
            ‘cosine’, ‘dice’, ‘euclidean’, ‘hamming’, ‘jaccard’, ‘jensenshannon’,
            ‘kulsinski’, ‘mahalanobis’, ‘matching’, ‘rogerstanimoto’, ‘sqeuclidean’,
            ‘russellrao’, ‘seuclidean’, ‘sokalmichener’, ‘sokalsneath’, ‘yule’.
        n_jobs : int or None, default=-1
            The number of processes to start -1 means use all processors 
        Attributes
        ----------
        labels : array, shape = [n_samples]
            Cluster labels for the data - noise is defined as -1
        References
        ----------
        Ester, M., H. P. Kriegel, J. Sander, and X. Xu, "A Density-Based
        Algorithm for Discovering Clusters in Large Spatial Databases with Noise".
        In: Proceedings of the 2nd International Conference on Knowledge Discovery
        and Data Mining, Portland, OR, AAAI Press, pp. 226-231. 1996
    """
        
    
        def __init__(self,
                     eps1=0.5,
                     eps2=10,
                     min_samples=5,
                     metric='euclidean',
                     n_jobs=-1):
            self.eps1 = eps1
            self.eps2 = eps2
            self.min_samples = min_samples
            self.metric = metric
            self.n_jobs = n_jobs
    
        def fit(self, X):
            
            Apply the ST DBSCAN algorithm 
            ----------
            X : 2D numpy array with
                The first element of the array should be the time 
                attribute as float. The following positions in the array are 
                treated as spatial coordinates. The structure should look like this [[time_step1, x, y], [time_step2, x, y]..]
                For example 2D dataset:
                array([[0,0.45,0.43],
                [0,0.54,0.34],...])
            Returns
            -------
            self
            
            # check if input is correct
            X = check_array(X)
    
            if not self.eps1 > 0.0 or not self.eps2 > 0.0 or not self.min_samples > 0.0:
                raise ValueError('eps1, eps2, minPts must be positive')
    
            n, m = X.shape
    
            
            # compute with quadratic memory consumption
    
            # Compute sqaured form Euclidean Distance Matrix for 'time' attribute and the spatial attributes
            time_dist = pdist(X[:, 0].reshape(n, 1), metric=self.metric)
            euc_dist = pdist(X[:, 1:], metric=self.metric)
    
            # filter the euc_dist matrix using the time_dist
            dist = np.where(time_dist <= self.eps2, euc_dist, 2 * self.eps1)
    
            db = DBSCAN(eps=self.eps1,
                            min_samples=self.min_samples,
                            metric='precomputed')
            db.fit(squareform(dist))
    
            self.labels = db.labels_
    
           
    
        return self
```

This is implemented in Euclidean metrics but when applying to geographical locations there is a problem with converting to cartesian coordinates. How can I change the class to handle a ball tree implementation with metrics haversine.